# Dojo tree selected node

Tags: tree, dojo

Upon creating a tree from a store in dojo, it seems to pre-select the top node in my tree; does anyone know how to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.mytree.lastFocused.setSelected(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no official way to prevent pre-selection, although if you don't want to show any selection ever, then just write a CSS rule to suppress that style:

```
.dijitTreeNodeSelected { background: none !important; }
```

or something like that.